# Is Deluge safe to use still when it's not been updated since the first part of 2017?

Tags: windows, torrent, bittorrent

https://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Download

https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/deluge/windows/?C=M;O=D

The latest version of Deluge for Windows that can actually be downloaded and installed is `deluge-1.3.15-win32-py2.7.exe` from **2017-05-12**.

That's well over **three years** ago now!

They have been discussing the problems of releasing the new version for years, but nothing comes from it. Like so many slowly dying (but never quite gone) projects I've painfully witnessed in the last many years.

Doesn't this more than likely make it extremely unsafe for me to be running this software on my machine? I feel as if it's an open door to my machine, almost certainly containing unpatched exploits.

Yet the sad reality is that there are no alternatives. uTorrent is an ad-infested spyware nightmare since many years, and others... well, just like with browsers, I've given up on searching because there's just nothing out there. Nobody seems to care one bit about the entirely desktop computer anymore.

Can I still use this ancient software? If so, how much longer?

Comment: Age of software alone says nothing about its quality and security. A recent version can be full of bugs and an old software can simply be feature-complete and stable. Essentially you are expecting us to do a security evaluation for you - which is off-topic.

Comment: Most GNU/Linux distributions have been on Deluge 2.0.3 for a while. Switching OS is easier than making a security evaluation like this for some old Windows executable. https://repology.org/project/deluge/versions

Answer (score 2):

A simple test is to check [exploit-db.com](https://www.exploit-db.com/) for vulnerabilities in this software:

[image: exploit-db search for 'deluge']

In the case of deluge 1.3.15, there are two Denial of Service vulnerabilities, but no others listed.  Depending on the requirements of the server you'd like to run this on, that may be an acceptable risk.

To be clear, this is only a limitation if running on Windows or MacOS.  Packages for the newest version, 2.0.3 (2019-06), are available for multiple variants of Linux.

Comment: This. I would also use cvedetails instead of exploit-db to get a better picture. I would also look at the version of python bundled with Deluge, as there could be a potential overlap there.